# How to bind a style's property?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml, binding

I have a few textboxes and would like to style each one with a watermark (ex: A textbox would contain the text 'Enter First Name Here' until you started typing in it.)

Normally I would just use a RelativeSource binding but I've encountered a weird bug where the Label inside the style won't accept any bindings that I throw at it. For example, the following Binding works everywhere but the Label's content:

```
{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Window}}, Path=Title}
```

For reference here is the code that I am working with.

TextBox's XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textBox_test" Style="{StaticResource textBoxStyle_watermark}" ToolTip="Hello"
```

Style's XAML:

```
<Style x:Key="textBoxStyle_watermark" TargetType="TextBox" xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
        <Style.Resources>
            <VisualBrush x:Key="CueBannerBrush" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="None">
                <VisualBrush.Visual>
                    <Label Padding="10,0,0,0" Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Path=ToolTip}" Foreground="Gray" />
                </VisualBrush.Visual>
            </VisualBrush>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Static sys:String.Empty}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="Text" Value="{x:Null}">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource CueBannerBrush}" />
            </Trigger>
            <Trigger Property="IsKeyboardFocused" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="White" />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
```

Any help would be appreciated, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem you've faced is *not related to styles setter value binding*, it's working fine. Issue in `Content` property and the way you're binding it to parent element.

**Problem:** You have always keep in mind that in **WPF** styles in resources are not treated as a part of template so *`TemplatedParent` as well as `AncestorType` will not work in style*.

**Solution:** *Use `ControlTemplate` with appropriate brush instead* which will allow access parent control of type `FrameworkElement` (or `TextBox`) and its `ToolTip` property.

Comment: Thanks for telling me about ControlTemplate! The watermark issue is now fixed, but I've encountered an issue with the tab control. I'll submit it as a different question though.